# SAS Proc SQL --- how to do Listagg function in SAS

Tags: sas, proc-sql

Good afternoon

I am looking for listagg function on SAS by using Proc SQL.

for example

```
id         product_name
1001        Bananas
1002        Bananas
1002        Apples
1002        Peach
1003        Pears

proc sql;
create table work.test2 as
select id, _____(',', product_name)
from  test1
group by id
order by 1;
quit;
```

Result

```
    id          product_name

    1001        Bananas
    1002        Bananas,Apples,Peach
    1003        Pears
```

There is function like this in SAS?

Comment: you can use first. and by variable to do this. you have to do this in datastep

Comment: SAS doesn't support list or pivot/window functions. However, there are many other ways to accomplish these types of tasks in SAS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do

```
data have;
input id product_name $;
datalines;
1001        Bananas
1002        Bananas
1002        Apples
1002        Peach
1003        Pears
 ;


  data want(rename=(product=product_name));
 do until(last.id);
 set have;
 by id;
 length product $50.;
  product =catx(',',product_name, product);
 end;
drop product_name;
run;
```

Comment: No need for the `IF/THEN/ELSE` when you have the `SET` statement inside the `DO` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of two approaches to a problem like this:

1. Is to do it in a data step and accumulate as you go through
2. Transpose the data to a wide format and then use a CAT function.

   ```
   *create sample data for demonstration;
   data have;
       infile cards dlm='09'x;
       input OrgID Product $   States $;
       cards;
   1   football    DC
   1   football    VA
   1   football    MD
   2   football    CA
   3   football    NV
   3   football    CA
   ;
   run;

   *Sort - required for both options;
   proc sort data=have;
       by orgID;
   run;

   **********************************************************************;
   *Use RETAIN and BY group processing to combine the information;
   **********************************************************************;
   data want_option1;
       set have;
       by orgID;
       length combined $100.;
       retain combined;

       if first.orgID then
           combined=states;
       else
           combined=catx(', ', combined, states);

       if last.orgID then
           output;
   run;

   **********************************************************************;
   *Transpose it to a wide format and then combine into a single field;
   **********************************************************************;
   proc transpose data=have out=wide prefix=state_;
       by orgID;
       var states;
   run;

   data want_option2;
       set wide;
       length combined $100.;
       combined=catx(', ', of state_:);
   run;
   ```