# Derive attributes based on multiple events

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I have data that I want to transpose to get visualization of the status of a single id at any point in time.

I have been trying to follow @Joe's answer from [Aggregating multiple observations depending on validity ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67491662/aggregating-multiple-observations-depending-on-validity-ranges), but I struggle with the case of multiple modalities attributes.

This is the event-based data I have:

```
data have;
infile datalines delimiter="|";
input attrib :$30. multiple_attr :$1. id :$30. attrib_id :8. member_value :$100. type :$5. dt_event :datetime18.;
format dt_event datetime20.;
datalines;
TYPE|N|ABC123|111|MEDIUM|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
TYPE|N|ABC123|111|MEDIUM|End|18APR2021:00:00:00
TYPE|N|ABC123|111|BIG|Start|19APR2021:00:00:00
TYPE|N|ABC123|111|BIG|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
POSITION|N|ABC123|222|TOP|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
POSITION|N|ABC123|222|TOP|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
IS_ACTIVE|N|ABC123|333|YES|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
IS_ACTIVE|N|ABC123|333|YES|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|ABC123|1|ALONE|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|ABC123|1|BOTH|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|ABC123|1|BOTH|End|18APR2021:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|ABC123|1|ALONE|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
TYPE|N|DEF456|111|MEDIUM|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
TYPE|N|DEF456|111|MEDIUM|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
POSITION|N|DEF456|222|MID|Start|01DEC2014:00:00:00
POSITION|N|DEF456|222|MID|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
IS_ACTIVE|N|DEF456|333|YES|Start|01MAR2014:00:00:00
IS_ACTIVE|N|DEF456|333|YES|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|ALONE|Start|01MAR2014:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|BOTH|Start|01MAR2014:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|BOTH|End|31MAR2018:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|BOTH|Start|20AUG2018:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|ALONE|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
LEVELS|Y|DEF456|1|BOTH|End|31DEC2030:00:00:00
;
```

Using @Joe's method:

```
proc sort data=have;
    by id attrib_id dt_event member_value;
run;

data want;
  set have(rename=member_value=in_value);
  by id attrib_id dt_event;
  retain start_date end_date member_value orig_value;
  format member_value new_value $100.;

  * First row per attrib_id is easy, just start it off with a START;
  if first.attrib_id then do;
    start_date = dt_event;
    member_value = in_value;
  end;     
  else do; *Now is the harder part;
    * For ENDs, we want to remove the current member_value from the concatenated value string, always, and then if it is the last row for that dt_event, we want to output a new record;
    if type='End' then do;
    
        *remove the current (in_)value;
        if first.dt_event then orig_value = member_value;
        do _i = 1 to countw(member_value,';');
            if scan(orig_value,_i,';') ne in_value then do;
                if orig_value > scan(orig_value,_i,';') then new_value = catx('; ',scan(orig_value,_i,';'),new_value);
                else new_value = catx('; ',new_value,scan(orig_value,_i,';'));
            end;
        end;
        orig_value = new_value;
 
        if last.dt_event then do;
            end_date = dt_event;
            output;
            start_date = dt_event + 86400;
            member_value = new_value;
            orig_value = ' ';
        end;
    end;
    else do;
        * For START, we want to be more careful about outputting, as this will output lots of unwanted rows if we do not take care;
        end_date = dt_event - 86400;
        if start_date < end_date and not missing(member_value) then output;
        if member_value > in_value then member_value = catx('; ',in_value,member_value);
        else member_value = catx('; ',member_value,in_value);
        start_date = dt_event;
        end_date = .;
    end;
  end;

  format start_date end_date datetime20.;
  keep id multiple_attr attrib_id member_value start_date end_date;
run;
```

I end up with:

```
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| multiple_attr |   id   | attrib_id |     start_date     |      end_date      |   member_value    |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| Y             | ABC123 |         1 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 18APR2021:00:00:00 | ALONE; BOTH       |
| Y             | ABC123 |         1 | 19APR2021:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | BOTH; ALONE       |
| N             | ABC123 |       111 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 18APR2021:00:00:00 | MEDIUM            |
| N             | ABC123 |       111 | 19APR2021:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | BIG               |
| N             | ABC123 |       222 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | TOP               |
| N             | ABC123 |       333 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | YES               |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 01MAR2014:00:00:00 | 31MAR2018:00:00:00 | ALONE; BOTH       |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 01APR2018:00:00:00 | 19AUG2018:00:00:00 | BOTH; ALONE       |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 20AUG2018:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | BOTH; BOTH; ALONE |
| N             | DEF456 |       111 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | MEDIUM            |
| N             | DEF456 |       222 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | MID               |
| N             | DEF456 |       333 | 01MAR2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | YES               |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+-------------------+
```

You can see that multiple modalities attributes (`where multiple_attr = "Y"`) are not handled properly.

The desired output should be like this:

```
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| multiple_attr |   id   | attrib_id |     start_date     |      end_date      | member_value |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
| Y             | ABC123 |         1 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 18APR2021:00:00:00 | ALONE; BOTH  |
| Y             | ABC123 |         1 | 19APR2021:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | ALONE        |
| N             | ABC123 |       111 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 18APR2021:00:00:00 | MEDIUM       |
| N             | ABC123 |       111 | 19APR2021:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | BIG          |
| N             | ABC123 |       222 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | TOP          |
| N             | ABC123 |       333 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | YES          |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 01MAR2014:00:00:00 | 31MAR2018:00:00:00 | ALONE; BOTH  |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 01APR2018:00:00:00 | 19AUG2018:00:00:00 | ALONE        |
| Y             | DEF456 |         1 | 20AUG2018:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | ALONE; BOTH  |
| N             | DEF456 |       111 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | MEDIUM       |
| N             | DEF456 |       222 | 01DEC2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | MID          |
| N             | DEF456 |       333 | 01MAR2014:00:00:00 | 31DEC2030:00:00:00 | YES          |
+---------------+--------+-----------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to handle multiple modalities attributes? I can't find a way to *delete* a member value once a modality of that attribute is ending (i.e. switching from `ALONE; BOTH` to `ALONE` after it ended).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure I understand *all* of this, but I think at least this is one problem.

Looking at where you remove the values, you need to use `strip` or similar because of spaces.  I removed the spaces in the `catx()` and add `strip()` to do that here.

```
        if strip(scan(orig_value,_i,';')) ne strip(in_value) then do;
            if strip(orig_value) > strip(scan(orig_value,_i,';')) then new_value = catx(';',scan(orig_value,_i,';'),new_value);
            else new_value = catx(';',new_value,scan(orig_value,_i,';'));
        end;
```

Otherwise it is comparing words with spaces to words without spaces, and while in some cases those words are identical (or treated as such by SAS), in some cases they aren't, which causes some of your issues here.  When I run this, I get "Alone" on the second line, for example.